# Using the "Offer" verb

Tags: verbs, verb-pattern

In a test I had earlier, there was a rewrite section where there was this sentence :

> John told Gary he would wash his car

Here is my rewrite :

> John offered his help in washing the car for Gary

According to my teacher, here is what  it is supposed to be :

> John offered to wash Gary's car

Efficiency and naturalness aside, is my sentence perfectly grammatical and does it retain most of the context ?

Comment: If a sentence is awkward, unnecessarily wordy, and clumsily worded, I have trouble deeming it "perfectly grammatical." There may be no grammatical error, but your version is poorly phrased nonetheless. There are alternate wordings, but I wouldn't count yours among them.

Answer (score 1):

> Is my sentence perfectly grammatical?

Yes it is.

> Does it retain most of the context ?

Not really. According to you, John will help Gary wash a specific (note the word 'the') car. But it doesn't say which/whose car. On the other hand, the original sentence clearly states that it is, in fact, Gary's car. Your teacher's version also states the same.